# How to solve upsert over two linked tables efficiently?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, upsert

I have a problem i can't seem to figure out without using very ineffecient code. The situation is that i have a Quarkus web service using Hibernate for database access and entity mappings. In it, there is a java entity called `SanctionedEntity` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sanctioned_entities")
public class SanctionedEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "sanctioned_entity_country_map", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "sanctioned_entity_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "country_id") }
    )
    private Set<Country> sanctioningCountries = new HashSet<>();
    //... get/set
}
```

with the following underlying SQL schema for the main entity:

```
CREATE TABLE sanctioned_entities (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(1024) NOT NULL
);
```

and the mapping to multiple `Country` entites per `SanctionedEntity` entity:

```
CREATE TABLE sanctioned_entity_country_map (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    sanctioned_entity_id bigint NOT NULL,
    country_id bigint NOT NULL
);
```

The problem is, i have to perform an insert of large data sets for new `SanctionedEntity` entities and their according `Country` entity mappings. Usually this would be no problem via Hibernate mappings, but it should not throw an exception on duplicates for the `name` field for `SanctionedEntity` entities but simply ignore them, but if a new `Country` mapping is not stored yet this should be saved in the mapping table.

My first thought was that i need to solve this with "upsert" statements, to ignore duplicates with **"ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING"** and then separately do another "upsert" statement in the mapping table for potential new `Country` mappings for it. So it would be two separate "upsert" statements. But Hibernate does not support "upsert" statements, so i have to resort to native SQL queries for the inserts.

The next problem is, that the IDs are not yet created for the `SanctionedEntity` objects IF they are new and will be added (as opposed to ignored if they already exist) which are necessary for the potential new mappings in the mapping table. But I can get them from the first query back using **"RETURNING id"**. Since the data sets are potentially large, i tried avoiding unnecessary repetitions over the data set but i kind of end up with a Java code solution where i have complexity of **O(n) + O(n * m)** since i first need to insert the entities to get the created IDs so i can then use them to iterate over all country mappings and insert them:

```
@Transactional
public void persistAllWithMultipleCountries(List<SanctionedEntity> sanctionedEntities) {
    StringBuilder entityValuesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder countryMapValuesBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (SanctionedEntity entity : sanctionedEntities) {
        addUpsertSanctionedEntitySqlFor(entity, entityValuesBuilder);
    }

    List<Long> ids = runSanctionedEntityUpsertFor(entityValuesBuilder);

    for (int i = 0; i < sanctionedEntities.size(); i++) {
        SanctionedEntity entity = sanctionedEntities.get(i);
        entity.setId(ids.get(i));
        addUpsertCountryMapsSqlFor(entity, countryMapValuesBuilder);
    }

    runEntityCountryMapsUpsertFor(countryMapValuesBuilder);
}

private void addUpsertSanctionedEntitySqlFor(SanctionedEntity entity, StringBuilder builder) {
    String currentTimestamp = new Date().toString();
    builder.append("(") 
        .append("'").append(entity.getName()).append("'")  
    .append("),");
}

private void addUpsertCountryMapsSqlFor(SanctionedEntity entity, StringBuilder builder) {
    entity.getSanctioningCountries().forEach(country -> {
        builder.append("(") 
            .append(entity.getId()).append(",")
            .append(country.getId())
        .append("),");
    });
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List<Long> runSanctionedEntityUpsertFor(StringBuilder builder) {
    String values = getChainedValuesWithoutLastRedundantComma(builder);
    String upsertSql = "INSERT INTO " 
        + "sanctioned_entities (name) " 
        + "VALUES " + values + " "
        + "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING "
        + "RETURNING id";
    return entityManager.createNativeQuery(upsertSql).getResultList();
}

private void runEntityCountryMapsUpsertFor(StringBuilder builder) {
    String values = getChainedValuesWithoutLastRedundantComma(builder);
    String upsertSql = "INSERT INTO " 
        + "sanctioned_entity_country_map (sanctioned_entity_id, country_id) " 
        + "VALUES " + values + " "
        + "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING";
    entityManager.createNativeQuery(upsertSql).executeUpdate();
}

private String getChainedValuesWithoutLastRedundantComma(StringBuilder builder) {
    return builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1).toString();
}
```

I don't think a really better solution can be done on the Java site here, so i was wondering if i maybe need to solve this with a stored procedure on the PostgreSQL server and call it. But i am unsure on how to pass all the data to the procedure in

1. a way so it stays cohesively together and
2. so it is syntactically functional in SQL?

Can anybody point me to a better solution or explain how this could be solved with a stored procedure?

Edit: I also just realized my code solution so far doesn't even fully work, because the set of created IDs may differ in length from the `SanctionedEntity` list i have before, since i only get the IDs of those rows created (and not of those ignored if they already existed). So i would have to merge them first by also returning them `name` field and map the IDs returned in the java code with the entities with the right name. This is just way too complicated, there has to be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the best you can do for now AFAICT. Hibernate will at some point add support for upserts, so you might be able to simplify that in the future.

I would also recommend that you don't inline all values and instead try to create a batch of e.g. 500 parameters instead. Execute that statement then with fresh parametrization over and over again.